# how can I lag a column in a data frame into a new column - i.e row 1 becomes row 2 in the new column?

Tags: r, lag

I have a time series: ts_1

I have converted it to a data frame: ts_1_reg

```
 ts_1_reg <- as.data.frame(ts_1)
```

[ts_1_reg][1]

What i am trying to do is create a new column in the data frame that lags the data in the Sales column --> i.e. the first row in the Sales column becomes the second row in a new column "L1_Sales". Meaning row 1 in the new column will just read 'NA'.

I tried

```
L1_Sales <- lag(ts_1_reg[,"Sales"], - 1)
ts_1_reg <- cbind(ts_1_reg, L1_Sales)
colnames(ts_1_reg) <- c("Sales", "L1_Sales")
```

However, this did not work. It simply duplicated the Sales column into the L1_Sales column with no lag.

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDtUs.png

Comment: Make sure you are using `dplyr::lag` (run `library(dplyr)` to load the package). The built-in `stats::lag` is a bit more counterintuitive. Also, you probably want the default `lag(, 1)` not `lag(, -1)`. And make sure you lag a column with it's current name. In the code you show it looks like you try to lag the "Sales" column **before** you give it the name `"Sales"`.

Comment: Thatnks for your help. I have written the following code: `df <- as.data.frame(ts_1)
colnames(df) <- c("Sales")
df %>% dplyr::mutate(L1_Sales = lag(Sales))`. This successfully creates the new L1_Sales column but the data is not lagged? Am i missing something? Also, using `, -1` or  `, 1` does not solve it.

Comment: Use `dplyr::lag`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do this:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Sales1 = lag(Sales))
```

Comment: A `library(dplyr)` or `dplyr::lag` might be good - part of OP's issue could be they are using `stats::lag` not `dplyr::lag`.